# Is there a way to tell whether a DC motor is brushed or brushless?

Tags: dc-motor

I have an actuator driven by a DC motor, and I can't find a datasheet for it (though it appears to be an [AL03S](https://www.linear-actuator.net.cn/product/linear-actuator/al03s-high-thrust-mini-linear-actuator.html).) I'd like to know if it's a brushless DC or brushed DC motor to ensure I purchase the correct motor driver IC.

[image: Motor type selector]

Also, I'm curious to know what would happen if I used a brushless DC motor driver IC to drive a brushed DC motor. I noticed that brushless DC motor driver ICs tend to be much cheaper.

Comment: "brushless" motors are not actually DC motors. I don't know why they get called that all the time.

Comment: @Hearth What is the correct term for a "brushless" DC motor? Is it "electronically commutated motor"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brushless_DC_electric_motor

Comment: The proper term is a "permanent magnet synchronous machine", or "permanent magnet AC motor". The method of control is *vastly* different from a DC motor, for the simple reason that one is DC and one is AC (among other things).

Comment: I suppose they're called DC motors because they're intended to be driven off a low-power DC rail using some variety of inverter. But I've never really liked that terminology as what they actually are is just a really small version of the large permanent-magnet motors used in electric vehicles and the like. (the really big industrial ones typically don't use a permanent magnet; they'd be wound-rotor machines, either synchronous or induction.)

Comment: @Hearth: like it or not, "brushless DC motor" refers to a specific type of synchronous motor, to wit, a motor whose back-EMF is trapezoidal with respect to the shaft position.  This means that it can be driven efficiently by switching a DC voltage to the coils in the right sequence.  A "brushless **AC** motor" is a different animal, referring to a motor whose back-EMF is sinusoidal; this can be driven more smoothly than a brushless DC motor, but the driver electronics needs to be fancier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Assure yourself it doesn't have built-in driver electronics.
- Count the wires, while paying attention to their sizes.

If there's two heavy wires, with or without light ones, it's a brushed DC motor.  If there's light wires, too, then chances are the motor has some feedback built in; either a tacho-generator (gives a voltage proportional to motor speed) or a shaft encoder of some sort.

If there's three heavy wires it's brushless, either "DC brushless"* or "AC brushless".  If it's *just* three heavy wires then its a sensorless motor, designed for use in a fan (or aircraft).  If it's three heavy wires and four or five light ones, then it's got hall sensors in it for commutation.  If it's three heavy wires and *more than* four or five light wires, then it's probably got the hall sensors *and* a rotary encoder, and there's a good chance that it's an AC brushless motor.

To be sure of things, put a voltmeter or oscilloscope on any two heavy wires and spin things by hand.  If it's the two wires on a brushed DC motor, then spinning it one way will generate a positive voltage, and spinning it the other will generate a negative voltage.  If it's a brushless motor then spinning it will generate an AC voltage.  If it's brushless and you have it on an oscilloscope, then if, when you spin it, you see a flat-topped wave, it's a DC brushless, and if you see a sinusoidal wave, it's an AC brushless.

* @Hearth: I don't like the terminology either.  But, it's established, so I'm stuck with it.

Answer (score 2):

The picture from your link shows the actuator has only two wires, so it should be a brushed motor.

To drive it in both directions, you'll need either a H-bridge driver (which can both reverse polarity and do PWM) or a DPDT relay for polarity plus a MOSFET and diode for PWM.

Two wires also means the limit switches are internal and not accessible. The switches are probably in series with the motor, so you will have to measure current to know if the motor is running or if it hit the limit switch.